# valid data verification through selenium RC/ Selenium 1.0

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-rc

How can we verify the data under **graphs/charts** via selenium RC.

I do not want to connect my selenium with database, Is it possible with any other way to verify the data present in graph. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.